# Mysql ERROR 1064 in syntax of over partition by

Tags: mysql

I recently updated my mysql instance on ubuntu to 8.0.26 from 5.7 to work with windowed functions. I checked the version with select @@version and it shows 8.0.26. But my queries to get data over partition by are still not working.

The table structure looks like this

```
Table sensor_data
id   asset_code   server_time
```

Below query gives Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

```
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_code ORDER BY server_time DESC) rank
FROM sensor_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `rank` alias you gave to the call to `ROW_NUMBER`.  In MySQL 8+, `RANK` becomes a reserved keyword referring to the analytic function `RANK()`.  Note that using an alias of `rank` on MySQL 5.7 and earlier was perfectly fine.  Just change the alias and your code should work:

```sql
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_code ORDER BY server_time DESC) rnk
FROM sensor_data
```

Comment: Alternatively, one can use a reserved keyword like `rank` as an alias by delimiting it in back-ticks.